# problema al ingresar en php con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo un crud por medio de  `ajax` y `php` pero mi problema es que en primer lugar no me esta ingresando nada pero cuando hago `echo` en `php` con las variables que tengo ahi, me las esta capturando todas y cuando estoy retornando por medio de un `json_encode` siempre me tira de status error y cuando quiero que me muestre el tipo de error no me esta capturando el `connect_error`, quisiera que me ayudaran muchas gracias les dejare el codio html, javascript y php

Codigo del HTMM

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="identificacion" type="text" class="validate" autofocus>
                            <label for="identificacion">Identificacion</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="fecha" type="text" class="datepicker">
                            <label for="fecha">Fecha de Ingreso:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="status">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Status</option>
                                <option>Reemplazo</option>
                                <option>Madre</option>
                                <option>Macho</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Status</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="motivo">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Motivo</option>
                                <option>Muerte</option>
                                <option>Sacrificio</option>
                                <option>Eliminado</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Motivo</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="causa_remocion">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Causa</option>
                                <option>Problemas Reproductivos</option>
                                <option>Cojeras</option>
                                <option>Enf. Sistematicas Especificas</option>
                                <option>Varios</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Causa de la Remocion</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="problemas_reproductivos">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="reproductivos">
                                <option value="null" selected>Problemas Reproductivos</option>
                                <option>Sin celo</option>
                                <option>No preñada</option>
                                <option>Negativa test de preñez</option>
                                <option>Vacia al Parto</option>
                                <option>Aborto</option>
                                <option>Libido Abajo(macho)</option>
                                <option>Baja Fetilidad(macho)</option>
                                <option>Parto Dificl</option>
                                <option>Prolapso Vaginal</option>
                                <option>Prolapso Uterino</option>
                                <option>Prolapso Rectal</option>
                                <option>Descarga Vaginal</option>
                                <option>Momificados</option>
                                <option>Cerdos Anormales</option>
                                <option>Camada Pobre</option>
                                <option>Camada Pequeña</option>
                                <option>Comportamiento Parto/Destete</option>
                                <option>Camada Enferma</option>
                                <option>Mastitis</option>
                                <option>Metritis</option>
                                <option>Problemas de Lactancia</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Tipos de Problemas Reproductivos</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="cojeras_heridas_degeneracion">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="cojeras">
                                <option value="null" selected>Cojeras,Heridas o Degeneraciones</option>
                                <option>Conformacion</option>
                                <option>Cojeras</option>
                                <option>Lesion de Pierna</option>
                                <option>Lesion de Pezuña</option>
                                <option>Hembra Caida</option>
                                <option>Herida</option>
                                <option>Abesos</option>
                                <option>Abesos</option>
                                <option>Ulcera</option>
                                <option>Flaca</option>
                                <option>Muy Grande</option>
                                <option>Muy Vieja</option>
                                <option>Sarna</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Tipos de Heridas,Cojeras o Degeneraciones</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="sistematica">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="enfasis">
                                <option value="null" selected>Enf. Sistematica Especifica</option>
                                <option>Enf. Genitourinaria</option>
                                <option>Enf. Cardiovascular</option>
                                <option>Enf. Gastrointestinal</option>
                                <option>Enf. en la Piel</option>
                                <option>Enf. del Sistema Nervioso</option>
                                <option>Enf. del Sistema Respiratorio</option>
                                <option>Enf. Musculoesqueletica</option>
                                <option>Enf. Desconocida</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Tipos de Enf. Sistematicas Especificas</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="otros_tipos">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <select id="varios">
                                <option value="null" selected>Otros Problemas</option>
                                <option>Muerte Repentina</option>
                                <option>Problemas de Conducta</option>
                                <option>Problemas de Mercado</option>
                                <option>Repoblacion</option>
                                <option>Probada y Eliminada</option>
                                <option>Desconocida</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Otros Tipos:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="fecha_salida" type="text" class="fecha_salida">
                            <label for="fecha_salida">Fecha de Salida</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="destino" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="destino">Destino:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cerrar</button>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="action">Enviar
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
                <div align="center" id="sending">
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Codigo de JQUERY, aclaro aqui algo cuando le hago `console.log` a data.status me sale indefinido no se porque

```
$("#action").click(function () {
    var json = {
        identificacion:$("#identificacion").val(),
        fecha:$("#fecha").val(),
        status:$("#status").val(),
        motivo:$("#motivo").val(),
        causa:$("#causa_remocion").val(),
        reproductivos:$("#reproductivos").val(),
        cojeras:$("#cojeras").val(),
        enfasis: $("#enfasis").val(),
        varios:$("#varios").val(),
        fecha_salida:$("#fecha_salida").val(),
        destino:$("#destino").val()
    }
    console.log(json);
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend:function () {
            $("#sending").show();
            $("#action").attr('disabled',true); 
        },
        url:'crud/create.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:json,
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data.status);
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                swal({
                    title:'Exito',
                    text: 'El Informe se ha Registrado Correctamente' ,
                    type: 'success',
                    showCancelButton:false,
                    confirmButtonClass:'btn-success',
                    confirmButtonText:'Recargar',
                    closeOnConfirm:false
                });
            }
            $("#sending").hide();
            $("#action").attr('disabled',false);
        },
        error:function (jqXHR,status,error) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete:function (jqHXR,status) {
            if (status == 'error') {
                swal({
                    title:'Ha ocurrido un Error, Intentalo Mas tarde',
                    text: status,
                    type:'error',
                    showCancelButton:false,
                    confirmButtonClass:'btn-danger',
                    confirmButtonText:'Reintentar',
                    closeOnConfirm:false
                })
            }
        },
        timeout:10000
    })
})
```

Codigo PHP

```
require_once '../connection/connection.php';
if ($_POST) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');  
    $data = array();
    $identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
    $causa = $_POST['causa'];
    $reproductivos = $_POST['reproductivos'];
    $cojeras = $_POST['cojeras'];
    $enfasis = $_POST['enfasis'];
    $varios = $_POST['varios'];
    $fecha_salida = $_POST['fecha_salida'];
    $destino = $_POST['destino'];

    // echo $identificacion. '<br>' .$fecha .'<br>' .$status .'<br>' .$motivo .'<br>' .$causa .'<br>' .$reproductivos .'<br>' .$cojeras .'<br>' .$enfasis .'<br>' .$varios .'<br>' .$fecha_salida .'<br>' .$destino;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Formulario_formato_descartes_core (identificacion, fecha, status, motivo, causa, reproductivos, heridas, enfasis, varios, fecha_salida, destino) VALUES ('$identificacion', '$fecha', '$status', '$motivo', '$causa', '$reproductivos', '$cojeras', '$enfasis', '$varios', '$fecha_salida', '$destino')";

    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['result'] = "Registro Ingresado Exisotasemente";
    }else{
        $data['status'] = "error";
        $data['result'] = "error :".$connect->connect_error;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    $connect->close();
}
```

quedo atento a cualquier duda o pregunta

Comment: Instead of `$connect->connect_error`, try `$connect->error`

Comment: quiza te sirva esto: http://www.phpcodify.com/insert-data-in-php-using-jquery-ajax-without-page-refresh/